# Joomla 3.0 installation with Wampserver 2.2

Tags: mysql, joomla

After using XAMPP for development purposes for a couple of years I'm starting with Wamp.

I created a database called "school" using phpMyAdmin, created a database user "admin" and password "admin".

When I get to the second page of the Joomla install I enter the above details, including Host Name: Localhost but get an error message "Could not connect to the database. Connector returned number: Could not connect to MySQL."

I know there must be some connection problem with the database but I'm scratching my head to find out what it is. Any suggestion would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you grant 'admin' user rights for school database?

Comment: If on localhost, why not just connect with root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you access the database from phpMyAdmin when you log in as admin? If not you should check admin's privileges. Give admin all privileges on that database; the default "Usage" permission is not enough. You can reduce the privileges afterwards if necessary.

If you can access it as admin from phpMyAdmin, double check on phpMyAdmin's privileges page that the admin's host is "localhost" since that what you're telling Joomla.

Also try both MySQL and MySQLi as the database type when installing Joomla.

Comment: You answer lead me to my problem, but my problem was different. While I was checking the admin privileges page, I noticed that it said password=NO. I most certainly set a password, but for some reason it didn't take, and so Joomla using a password was not working.